# Building a dictionary from 2 given lists in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I want to build a script getting 2 lists (same size) from the user, `L1` and `L2`, and build a `dictionary`: each `object` from `L1` is a key, and each object from `L2` is the `value` (for same index)

I'm trying to make a combined list first, in order to use the `dict()` function.

here is my script. It runs, but prints nothing. I want to print just to make sure I get build the right list to apply the `dict()` function to...

```
    print 'enter 2 lists with same len:'

L1=input('enter first list:')
L2=input('enter second list:')

if len(L1)==len(L2) and isinstance(L1,list) and isinstance(L2, list):
    D_list=[]
    D_ij=[]
    for i in L1:
        if isinstance (i,(int, str)):
            for j in L2:
                if isinstance(j, (tuple, list)):

                    for i in L1:
                        for j in L2:



                            D_ij=[L1[i], L2[j]]
                            D_list.extend([D_ij])

                            print D_list

else: print 'error'
```

Comment: You also need to make sure the list1 items are hashable

Answer (score 4):

You need `zip` function:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip

You can build dictionary like this:

```
my_dict = dict(zip(list_1, list_2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {k:v for k,v in zip(L1,L2)}
```

Comment: this returns a set dude, no even a dict

Comment: my bad...confused syntax .. :P

Comment: May the down voter BE GENEROUS and spare his time to explain what's the reason behind his DOWN VOTE !!